# The means for Applescript to access the PDF menu button from the Chrome Print window changed in Sonoma

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, pdf

I have an AppleScript that used to work to print a Chrome tab to pdf.

I recently updated to Sonoma and the script no longer works.  I have not run the script for a long time, so I don't know that it is specific to Sonoma.

My Chrome version is 120.0.6099.71

```
        tell process "Chrome"
            set frontmost to true
            
            # Open the print dialog
            keystroke "p" using {command down, option down}
            
            
            
            # Wait until the Print dialog opens before proceeding
            set loopcount to 0
            repeat until exists window "Print"
                set loopcout to loopcount + 1
                if loopcount > 50 then
                    display dialog "Print window not found"
                end if
                
            end repeat
            
            key code 48 # send tab character to go to first page
            key code 48 # send tab character to go to last page
            keystroke "1" # make page 1 last page
            key code 48 # tab to scale box
            keystroke "90" # set scale to 90            
            # Expand the "PDF" menu button (must be expanded before the menu is referencable)
            delay 1
            click menu button "PDF" of window "Print"
            
            # Wait until the Menu button menu is created before proceeding
            repeat until exists menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF" of window "Print"
            end repeat
            # Select the "Save as PDF" menu item
            click menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF" of window "Print"
            
            # Wait until the Save dialog opens before proceeding
            repeat until exists button "Save" of sheet 1 of window "Print"
            end repeat
            
            # Paste the filename in  and Save
            
            set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of window "Print" to "testfile.pdf"
            
            click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window "Print"
            
            delay 1
            
        end tell
        #display dialog "myURL: " & myURL
        
    end tell
```

When I run this code I now get the following error:

`error "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu button \"PDF\" of window \"Print\" of process \"Chrome\"." number -1728 from menu button "PDF" of window "Print" of process "Chrome"`

Can you help me figure out how to open the PDF print window from AppleScript?

Comment: The PDF button changed in Sonoma, and is a different type of object. This is the trouble with GUI scripting -- scripting what the user does to trigger commands, rather than just scripting the commands themselves. You can (or could) set a key command for "PDF" -- even using Command P again for that, and then just script two Command P presses. It might be possible to automate creating a PDF with Shortcuts.app. Of course, Safari has an Export To PDF command.

Comment: Thanks for that input.  Is there a way to find out the type of object the PDF button is?  Export to PDF is also available in Chrome, but I'd like to scale it as well, which the Print to PDF option allows.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @benwiggy, I found out that the UI changed in Sonoma.  So I spent some time trying to figure out how to figure out what element the PDF button is in Sonoma.

I found this answer on stackexchange to be useful:

[How to enumerate the UI elements in applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231133/use-applescript-to-list-the-names-of-all-ui-elements-in-a-window-gui-scripting)

You can also use [UIBrowser3](https://latenightsw.com/freeware/ui-browser/), which is more convenient than the AppleScript method.

I discovered that the PDF button is now:

`menu button 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Print"`

Which leads to the revised (and working) code:

```
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Chrome"
            set frontmost to true
            delay 1
            
            # Open the print dialog
            keystroke "p" using {command down, option down}
            
            
            
            # Wait until the Print dialog opens before proceeding
            set repeatcount to 0
            repeat until exists window "Print"
                set repeatcount to repeatcount + 1
                if repeatcount > 50 then
                    display dialog "Print window not detected"
                end if
            end repeat
            
            key code 48 # send tab character to go to first page
            key code 48 # send tab character to go to last page
            keystroke "1" # make page 1 last page
            key code 48 # tab to scale box
            keystroke "90" # set scale to 90    
            #set UIElems to UI elements of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Print"
            #display dialog UIElems
            # Expand the "PDF" menu button (must be expanded before the menu is referencable)
            click menu button 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Print"
            
            # Wait until the Menu button menu is created before proceeding
            #delay 2
            repeat until exists menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Print"
            end repeat
            # Select the "Save as PDF" menu item
            click menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Print"
            
            # Wait until the Save dialog opens before proceeding
            repeat until exists button "Save" of sheet 1 of window "Print"
            end repeat
            
            # Paste the filename in  and Save
            
            set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of window "Print" to SaveFileName
            
            click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window "Print"
```

As @benwiggy points out, this may be less than optimal, because the logical structure of the user interface elements can change at any time (as shown by Sonoma), but it is useful for my application and for occasional scripting.